# ESP32 seconds from epoch

Tags: esp32, time

When using ESP8266 - getting seconds from epoch is done using

```
NTP.begin(NTPserver, 2, true);
delay(delay_tries);
time_t t = now();
```

while `t` stores amount of seconds from 1-1-1970.

When trying to do the same, using ESP32 - I cant get that numeric representation.

code below is from ESP32 example- updating time using NTP server ( process is done correct ). BUT when using `now()` yields 1970, as if NTP update has never occured.

How can I get time from Epoch ?

```
#include <WiFi.h>
#include "time.h"
#include <TimeLib.h>    <------- Added to original Code

const char* ssid       = "YOUR_SSID";
const char* password   = "YOUR_PASS";

const char* ntpServer = "pool.ntp.org";
const long  gmtOffset_sec = 3600;
const int   daylightOffset_sec = 3600;

void printLocalTime()
{
  struct tm timeinfo;
  if(!getLocalTime(&timeinfo)){
    Serial.println("Failed to obtain time");
    return;
  }
  Serial.println(&timeinfo, "%A, %B %d %Y %H:%M:%S");
}

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);

  //connect to WiFi
  Serial.printf("Connecting to %s ", ssid);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
      delay(500);
      Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println(" CONNECTED");

  //init and get the time
  configTime(gmtOffset_sec, daylightOffset_sec, ntpServer);
  printLocalTime();

  //disconnect WiFi as it's no longer needed
  WiFi.disconnect(true);
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_OFF);
}

void loop()
{
  delay(1000);
  printLocalTime();
  Serial.println(now());   <-------- Added to original code
}
```

Comment: where is `now()` defined or even used in the code you posted?

Comment: Does your code output `"Failed to obtain time"`?

Comment: try `time(nullptr)` instead of `now()` - since `now()` is not even a valid function in the code you posted

Comment: you can use the NTP library on ESP32 and you can use the SDK time functions on esp8266 too

Comment: @JaromandaX - sorry, now with 2 additional line to original code

Comment: @Juraj - Also with `#include <NTPClient.h>` and `timeClient.begin();` `    timeClient.setTimeOffset(3600);` yeilds the same result ( time is updated, but cant get epoch )\

Comment: @Guy.D - just because you added `now()` to the code you've shown, doesn't make it valid (if I try to use `now()` in ESP32 code, it doesn't even **compile** :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to return 'epoch' seconds there is a function `time` in time.h

```
time_t now;
time(&now);
```

`time_t` is defined as `long`

this time is retrieved by the ESP32 SDK from NTP servers configured with  ESP32 Arduino function `configTime`

EDIT: it is the standard C `time()` [function](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_time.htm)

Comment: since `time` also returns a `time_t` you can use it like `now()` ... i.e.  `time(nullptr);`