# ESP32 documentaiont for "time.h"

Tags: esp32, time, documentation

I am working from the example sketch in that [installed](https://randomnerdtutorials.com/installing-the-esp32-board-in-arduino-ide-windows-instructions/) with the ESP32 Dev Module into the Arduino IDE.  It includes `<WiFi.h>` and `"time.h"`.  I have a number of questions about how to use the clock that is set up with `configTime` using NTP. I am trying to find the documentation, but I'm having difficulty identifying exactly who is providing me the `"time.h"` header file, and of course, there are a lot of different `time.h` header files out there so googling is difficult.

Where can I find the documentation for this particular header?

---

Example questions:

- Can the time be set manually without a WiFi connection?
- Can the timezone be changed without connecting to NTP again?
- Can I get the time as a Unix Time Stamp?  ([Yes](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/71453/esp32-seconds-from-epoch))
- Can I arrange for a function callback at a certain time? (I'm aware I can use the timer library for this but I'm hoping for something like a callback at 4:20p every Saturday)

Comment: have you checked in the library for documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`time.h` is provided by the compiler (more specifically the C library in use in the compiler).

I believe the xtensa-esp32 compiler uses *newlib* as the C library. If that is the case, the documentation is here: https://sourceware.org/newlib/libc.html#Timefns

Comment: So, time.h is not where `configTime(...)` is defined then?

Comment: No. `configTime()` is part of the ESP32 core.  https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/cores/esp32/esp32-hal-time.c#L47